# rspec ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby, rspec, puppet

I am trying to use rspec with puppet to check the generation of a configuration file from an .erb file. However, I get the error

```
1) customizations should generate valid logstash.conf
     Failure/Error: content = catalogue.resource('file', 'logstash.conf').send(:parameters)[:content]
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
     # ./spec/classes/logstash_spec.rb:29:in `catalogue'
     # ./spec/classes/logstash_spec.rb:29
```

And the **logstash_spec.rb**:

```
describe "customizations" do
    let(:params) { {:template => "profiles/logstash/output_broker.erb", :options => {'opt_a' => 'value_a' } } }
    it 'should generate valid logstash.conf' do
      content = catalogue.resource('file', 'logstash.conf').send(:parameters)[:content]
      content.should match('logstash')
    end
end
```

How do I fix the error "wrong number of arguments"?

Comment: where is the original code for which you wrote the TDD ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: The puppet manifests? The logstash_spec.rb is where the tests are run.

Comment: I think `send(:parameters)` should be `send(:params)`. Because `let(:params)..` I can see.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: I thought the same thing actually.. I tried that but it gives me the same error. Coincidentally, this slideshow shows using `parameters`: http://www.slideshare.net/PuppetLabs/automated-puppet-testing-puppetcamp-chicago-12-scott-nottingham

Comment: @sawa: I think it is pretty clear that the problem is the error posted first.

Comment: show the content of `logstash.rb`

Comment: @ArupRakshit: There is no such file.

Comment: I believe you'd want to invoke `catalogue.resource('file', 'logstash.conf').send(:parameters, :content)`, but then the whole approach appears flawed to me. See my answer concerning `rspec-puppet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing `rspec` and `rspec-puppet` style code.

If you are testing your `logstash` class, your [rspec-puppet](https://github.com/puppetlabs/rspec-puppet) code should look like

```
# spec/classes/logstash_spec.rb

require "#{File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'..','spec_helper.rb')}"

describe 'logstash' do
  let(:params) { {:template => "profiles/logstash/output_broker.erb", :options => {'opt_a' => 'value_a' } } }
  it { should contain_file('logstash.conf').with_content(/logstash/) }
end
```

Note that I never tried with regex in this context, but that is the general structure you want to follow.

Comment: I see. So this is what I am doing. I am indirectly testing if the puppet logstash module creates my logstash.conf and not a blank or empty logstash.conf that I have had a problem with before for an invalid erb. So what I am not clear on is if I should be checking for the existence of logstash.conf which is created by the module at /etc/logstash/conf.d on the host, or something else altogether. This is the puppet logstash code that checks if the logstash.conf is properly populated. https://github.com/elasticsearch/puppet-logstash/blob/master/spec/defines/003_logstash_configfile_spec.rb

Comment: I'd recommend testing the module using `rspec-puppet`. If the manifest is proven to contain an appropriate `file` resource with the `content` property set, then it is safe to assume that the `puppet agent` will install that to the machine correctly. Testing for the end result on the agent machine is rather at the acceptance test scope, and more difficult to get right IMO.

Comment: thanks for the help.. used this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18483009/2591612) to test my template creation before doing a puppet run on the agent. I put it under my `template` directory under a directory called `tests`.

Comment: That is arguably simpler than setting up `rspec-puppet`, yes. Way to go.